# Duke - org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, jar, lucene, standardanalyzer, duke

https://github.com/larsga/Duke - I am using Duke - for Data Deduplication.

I have setup Duke (jar files - Duke jar as well as lucene jars are added in the classpath) ..

Sample example in the github- https://github.com/larsga/Duke/wiki/SemanticDogfood

```
When I tried running this : 
soundaryat@IMCHLT132:~/Duke$ java no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke --testfile=doc/example-data/dogfood-test.txt --testdebug --showmatches doc/example-data/dogfood.xml

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer.<init>(Lorg/apache/lucene/util/Version;)V
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.databases.LuceneDatabase.<init>(LuceneDatabase.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.ConfigLoader.instantiate(ConfigLoader.java:292)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.ConfigLoader.access$100(ConfigLoader.java:31)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.ConfigLoader$ConfigHandler.startElement(ConfigLoader.java:199)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1140)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.ConfigLoader.load(ConfigLoader.java:49)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke.main_(Duke.java:64)
    at no.priv.garshol.duke.Duke.main(Duke.java:35)
```

whereas, the other example in the same github works - https://github.com/larsga/Duke/wiki/LinkingCountries

can anyone help,.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and by googling I've found out that Duke is not compatible with latest versions of Lucene. Are you using Lucene 5.X? 
If that's the case, you should download the older versions of Lucene jars (4.0.0) and include them in the classpath. It worked for me!

Comment: Hi Enri. Can you please check my comment above. Thank you :-)

Comment: This is correct. Duke suffered a substantial slowdown with Lucene 5.x, because of how Lucene does compression of small fields in the index. I tried a few different ways to fix it, but in the end it was too much work.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the particular example from the github repository.

There is a file missing in the https://github.com/larsga/Duke/wiki/SemanticDogfood from the config file. (i found out from the config file) .. there are some dependency files missing out for the particular example. So got resolved. :)

Thanks for your reply Enri as well.

Answer (score 0):

Include these jar files in class path:

```
lucene-core-4.0.0.jar
lucene-analyzers-common-4.2.0.jar
lucene-6.3.0.jar
duke-1.2.jar:
.
$CLASSPATH
```